# Reescribir una variable global

Tags: python, variables, class, pycharm, alcance

Quiero mirar si mi variable global item se reescribe con el contenido de la variable `item` de mi función `copy()`

No se como interpretar los alcances

El problema es que cuando se llama la clase `register()` y se instancia el objeto `proof`, el valor que nuevamente retorna es `[0]`, lo cual no es lo que deseo, deseo reescribir y que me quede con el valor de la variable de la función `copy()`

```
class register():
    item = [0]
    print(f'item before function -> {item} <id> = {id(item)}')
    def __init__(self, quantity = '20', fabric_c = 'client', fabric_p = 'own'):
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.fabric_c = fabric_c
        self.fabric_p = fabric_p
        p_c = True
    def copy(self):
        if p_c == True:
            line = self.quantity + ' meters ' + self.fabric_c
            item = line
            print(f'printing description during execution function -> {line} <id> = {id(item)})')
        return item
        print(f'item after function -> {item} <id> = {id(item)}')
proof = register()
proof.copy()

print(f'proof.item = {proof.item} outside of class -> {id(proof.item)}')

# [out] : item before function -> [0] <id> = 140627839165312

# [out] : printing description during execution function -> 20 meters client <id> = 140627839182128)

# [out] : proof.item = [0] outside of class -> 140627839165312
```

Al comparar los valores de `id` confirmo que el `id` de mi función no es la misma que la que se declaro afuera de la función.

Comment: This site in is Spanish, translate your question or ask in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) (english version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de la función `copy()` no estás haciendo referencia al miembro de la clase, sino definiendo una nueva variable (local para dicha función).

Si quieres hacer referencia al miembro de la clase, califícalo con `self`, de manera que sería `self.item`:

```
    def copy(self):
        if p_c == True:
            line = self.quantity + ' meters ' + self.fabric_c
            self.item = line
            print(f'printing description during execution function -> {line} <id> = {id(self.item)})')
        return item
```

Esto es necesario porque `self` es una referencia a la instancia sobre la que se llama el método.